# vsvim code expand/collapse or fold/unfold shortcut in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, vim, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts, vsvim

<kbd>ctrl+m</kbd> used to work as collapse/uncollapse shortcut before I installed vsvim. After installing vsvim using the <kbd>zo</kbd> command is uncollapsing a C# region block. But do not have a shortcut to fold till the end of the region. Using <kbd>zf/string</kbd> folds incorrectly. There should be a better shortcut.

Comment: If you want to keep using `Ctrl+M` you can do so by just reassigning the shortcut back to Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reassigned the <kbd>ctrm+m</kbd> to be used. This could be done using the **Options** button shown at the bottom of the editor. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone having the issue still, using he `vscodevim` plugin provides

- <kbd>zc</kbd> folds a region
- <kbd>zo</kbd> unfold a region